# Finding constants from a decrypted iOS app executable

Tags: ios, security, reverse-engineering, dump, decompiling

I'm trying to find a constant (something like a secret token) from inside of an iOS app in order to build an app using an undocumented web API (by the way, I'm not into something illegal). So far, I have the decrypted app executable on my Mac (jailbreak + SSH + dumping decrypted executable as file). I can use the strings command to get a readable list of strings, and I can use the class-dump tool (http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) to get a list of interface definitions (headers) of the classes. Although this gives me an idea of the app's inner workings, I still can't find what I'm searching for: the constants I'm looking for. There are literally thousands of string definitions in the strings command dump. Is there any way to dump the strings in a way that I can have the names of the NSString constants with their values. I don't need the implementation details of the methods, I know that it's compiled and all I can get is assembly code. But if I can get the names of the string constants (both in strings dump and class dump) and also the string values (in strings dump), I think there may be a way to associate them together.

Thanks,

Can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, unless there's some black magic tool out there that I'm unaware of, or unless the executable was built with debug symbols (which is likely not the case).  If there are debug symbols, you should be able to run it through a debugger and get variable names.

At compile time, the compiler strips off the name of the constant, and replaces all occurrences of the constant in the code with the address of its location in memory (which is *usually* the same byte offset as inside the executable).  Because of this, the original variable naming of the constant is lost, leaving only the value.  Hence, the reason you can't find the constants anywhere.

Something that I would do to try to find the secret token, is capture all the data traffic that the app creates, and then look for the same patterns in the binary.  If the token is indeed in there, and it isn't obfuscated somehow, then at least that narrows it down for you greatly.

Good luck!  RE can be very rewarding but sometimes it really sucks.

Comment: the token is (has to be) somewhere there in the executable, as the API calls contain a signature that is hashed with some other variables (it is using amazon aws service, but unfortunately thats only one part of the work). if I can't get the constant name, i may be able to at least get what objc method is called with which variable (even if I don't know the name), that would be enough because I'm focused on a specific method that I know the name of (and I can see that method after a header dump), logically I should find out when its called with the right tools.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu  Yes the token is somewhere in the executable.  You are on the right track, hunting for the method names that use it.  Based on your question and the reference to Steve Nygard's class-dump, I would assume you have a list of all the method names?

Comment: yes, I (believe) that I have them all as objective c class headers. now I'm using cycript ana inalyzer to hook into the working app to find out the token.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu  Sweet!  This sounds like a lot of fun!

Comment: update: yeah, cycript worked. i successfully got the secret token from the running binary.