# Is there a way to get exported constants from an Objective-C framework?

Tags: objective-c, macos, debugging, otool

Is there a way to extract the exported constants' name and value from an Objective-c framework? For example, from Foundation framework, there is an enum `NSEnumerationReverse`. How to extract such enum as well as any constants with the corresponding value?

I am looking from something like a file which will output the name-value mapping

```
NSEnumerationReverse = (1UL << 1)
```

I am only able to get the exported classes and method using otool.

Comment: I think it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129004/10900045

Comment: Correct, not possible to extract from the compiled framework/executable. That’s why Objective-C frameworks are distributed with header (`.h`) files, which declare those constants that are exposed to application developers.